# I use GraphAPI created an onlinemeeting. How do I get the participates info (start/end date) etc.after the meeting?

Tags: graph, microsoft-teams, c3.js

Our school wants to do virtual campus visit. So the plan is to create onlinemeeting then when a student register to a campus visit, add the student as a participate. At the visit time, the instructor and students will use the MS Teams to communicate. After the meeting, our program will get the meeting/caller info and process it. My code called "await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting);" I can get the id/joinweburl(no videoTeleconferenceId) from the meeting object created. I am not sure how to retrieve the callers' info after the meeting.
Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The videoTeleconferenceId comes from the meeting room devices, which are generated for Cloud-Video-Interop licensed users. You will require license for [Get meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) details API.

if the response get VTC id as null, GET online meeting API will not work as expected.
You can try to use [CreateOrGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-createorget?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) api for the same, There you need to specify a custom external Id. If you have a need to embed an online meeting within a custom calendar and if you specify an external ID to associate the online meeting. This API is in Beta, This is expected to change in future.

Answer (score 0):

Trinetra-MSFT,i have a related question... I am really confused and you are the one who had most answered graph.api questions...
I know that when i create an onlinemeeting it's not seen on calendar.. but it's not seeable anywhere?
As a second, i am trying to create this meeting on a channel but not with http, i am using graph api on c#. In http sample it shows that must add a chatinfo. But when i add this, i got error that chatinfo must be null..
As a third and last, when i create an event (not onlinemeeting) and when i add an organizer, it's not readed by api... it doesn't matter what i wrote to organizer, it takes group as organizer... And doesn't let anyone to edit this event...

```
                            var @event = new Event
                            {
                                Subject = dety.ders_kodu,
                                Body = new ItemBody
                                {
                                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                                    Content = dety.ders_kodu + " Canlı Dersi"
                                },
                                Location = new Location
                                {
                                    DisplayName = grubu.DisplayName
                                },
                                Attendees = AttendeeList,
                                Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
                                {
                                    DateTime = baslangicTarihi,
                                    TimeZone = "Europe/Istanbul"
                                },
                                End = new DateTimeTimeZone
                                {
                                    DateTime = bitisTarihi,
                                    TimeZone = "Europe/Istanbul"
                                },
                                Organizer = new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = dety.akamicname, Name = dety.akamicname } },
                                IsOrganizer = true,

                                Recurrence = new PatternedRecurrence
                                {
                                    Pattern = new RecurrencePattern
                                    {
                                        Type = RecurrencePatternType.Weekly,
                                        Interval = 1,
                                        DaysOfWeek = new List<Microsoft.Graph.DayOfWeek>() { dayOf }
                                    },
                                    Range = new RecurrenceRange
                                    {
                                        Type = RecurrenceRangeType.EndDate,
                                        EndDate = new Date(2020, 12, 4),
                                        StartDate = new Date(2020, 10, 19),
                                        RecurrenceTimeZone = "Europe/Istanbul"
                                    }
                                },
                                AllowNewTimeProposals = true,
                                IsOnlineMeeting = true,
                                OnlineMeetingProvider = OnlineMeetingProviderType.TeamsForBusiness,
                                TransactionId = transact
                            };
                            var even = await graphClient.Groups[akad.dersmickod].Events
                                      .Request()
                                      .AddAsync(@event).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Your are creating event on behalf of group? Events are displayed in calendar,  Let me run your code will get back to you in sometime

Comment: I have the same experience that "adding organizer" doesn't work. It will set me (the credential that run the code) as organizer.

Comment: yes Trinetra... Trying to create behalf of group... (group is a team class)